# join table grows massively

Tags: mysql, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, database, nosql

I have a join table in my application's database (MySQL) which grows massively.

I have 2 models user and product, user has many products to view, and products belongs to many users how will view it.
on start all users has all products to view and the user can edit which products he can view.

the problem that the table size will be (n*m) n is number of users (which is large) and m is number of products (which is large too), and read operations on the table will be slow.

Example:
I have 3 Users their id's : "1,2,3"
and 3 products their id's : "1,2,3"

so the users_products table will be:

> user_id, product_id
>   1 , 1
>   1 , 2
>   1 , 3
>   2 , 1
>   2 , 2
>   2 , 3
>   3 , 1
>   3 , 2
>   3 , 3

I'm open to all solutions, starting from redesigning this part to use another database system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "and read operations on the table will be slow." Why do you think it will be slow? Do you have any empirical evidence to back up this claim? Have you tried adding indexes?

Comment: Your idea is the classic solution.. Keep in mind that this table only has 2 fields, and an index on the 'user_id' column would produce quick results.

Comment: @EranBane: I know that the record is just 2 integers and won't take that amount of space, but i was investigating in this point, to prevent future problems.

Comment: @MarkByers: @ now i don't have that statistics.

Comment: It is very important to know the size that you are dealing with.  For thousands of users and hundreds of products, your approach is fine (with indices).  For milllions of users and thousands of products, we need more information -- How often are users and products updated/inserted/deleted?  Is the access path always from users --> products?  What are the performance requirements for the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your assuming something that probably isn't true. SQL servers are quick with these kind of queries even with a lot of rows. Tables with 10 million records can be queried pretty fast if you have good indices.

I would recommend some testing before you make all kinds of premature optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Neo4J? It's a well-documented Graph Database, which in my opinion is perfect for this particular use case. The way you go about modeling this is so easy.

Every user and every product is represented by a node. You either create a relation "IS_ABLE_TO_SEE" between them, or you don't.

You can then use a whole range of functionalities to retrieve this data again. A favourite of mine is the use of traversals, where you start at a node, and you walk over the relations (you can choose which ones to walk over and in what direction). However, this is more useful for retrieving data that is several levels of depth away from eachother.

In our particular use case, you could do a simple query returning all of the product nodes that are connected to your user node via the relation "IS_ABLE_TO_SEE".

Neo4J is very accessible for people with no experience in graph databases, and as I said, it's pretty much made for the use case you present here.

Answer (score 0):

As Pieter-Jan pointed out with Neo4J there are alternative solutions, I am a big fan of both Couchbase and Neo4J. This is a simple list, and relational tables aren't as well suited for these operations.

In Couchbase you can do this multiple ways, one would be to use simple client.append to keep a list of products, then a single client.get to retrieve the list. With this there are two possibilities, dedupe before append, or dedupe after. Extremely fast for grabbing a list, will obliterate any form of querying.

Another way would be to use JSON, and have an array of each product the user has access to, and viewed, etc. Same with the simple string above in the first example, except you can then do Map/Reduce on it if it's in JSON, if needed.

In both cases it will outperform any type of querying.